# Understanding minispade filter

Tags: rake, ember.js, asset-pipeline

The Minispade filter wraps each file's code within a closure. Now, for object defined in a file that were supposed to be exposed globally, they are no longer global as they get wrapped in a closure.

So, how do we actually require objects defined in a separate file in our main app file?

This is my example.

In my file, test.js

```js
var test = { sayHello: function(){alert('hello');} }
```

In my main app file, I do:

```js
require('todos/vendor/jquery-1.7.1');
require('todos/vendor/ember-0.9.5');
require('todos/vendor/test');

console.log(jQuery); // this logs the jQuery object
console.log(Ember);  // this logs the Ember object
console.log(test);   // this is undefined
```

How do I access the `test` object within my main app js file ? Is it that I have to define my `test` object in a different way in my file?

**UPDATE:**

I can leak objects to global namespace by removing the `var` but is that the recommended approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of minispade is to contain these "files" inside their own closures so they do not leak into the global name space. Letting `test` leak like that without var is a bad idea and you are probably trying to use minispade to solve the wrong problem.

The popular minispade pattern is to define a globally available variable (in Ember terms, this would be an Ember Namespace or `App`). Then each of your minispade closures will build onto App by adding models, views, controllers, etc. For example.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
```

Then in minispade you would create a minispade closure for vehicle.js

```
App.Vehicle = Ember.Object.extend();
```

And we would also create a minispade closure for car.js.

```
require('vehicle');

App.Car = App.Vehicle.extend();
```

This will ensure that vehicle is loaded and executed before we attempt to define car.

You might want to take a look at this: http://ryanto.github.com/#posts/rake-pipeline-assetfile (it's a work in progress, but there is a section on using minispade with rake pipeline).

Comment: I suspected that. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: +1 for the rake-pipeline-assetfile guide. Been looking for something exactly like that.